# When do we assume a wireless communications' channel reciprocity and non-reciprocity?

Tags: signal, wireless, digital-communications

When I read wireless communications literature, I encountered both channel reciprocity and non-reciprocity assumptions for two-way communication scenarios involving A-to-B and B-to-A fading channels.

Under what channel characteristics do we assume that A-to-B and B-to-A fading channels are reciprocal or non-reciprocal?

Comment: Well "we" do that when the physics of our problem suggest we should do that: some communication scenarios have reciprocal channels, some don't. If you use the same channel within its coherence time in both directions, it might be reciprocal. If you use 406 MHz for uplink and 1400 MHz for downlink, the channels are probably not the same. So, not really sure I answered the question, but as always: we use some model when it is for to describe reality for our purposes. That applies to any model, not just channels.